# What's the fastest way to go down a directory and read in multiple excel workbooks with multiple tabs?

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, optimization, pickle

I would like to go into a directory and retrieve every excel workbook that meets the criteria in my if statement (if the extension is ".xlsb" and the letters "USA" are in the name). The excel workbooks have multiple tabs and I need to be able to view the contents of them. My code works fine, but it's painfully slow. Is there a faster method of doing this? I believe the pd.read_excel is what's taking the longest time.

I thought maybe converting the files to a pickle would speed it up, but I don't know how to do that without first reading in the file as a dataframe.

My code returns a list of workbooks in dictionary format (Sheet name: Sheet contents)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
rootdir = "SOME PATH"
wbs = [] #instantiate workbook list
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir, topdown = False):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".xlsb") and "USA" in file.lower(): # if the file name has USA in it
            temp_list = [] # create a list of sheets
            wb_dict = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(subdir, file), sheet_name = None) #create the dfs
            temp_list.append(wb_dict)           
    wbs = wbs + temp_list
    temp_list = []
```

Comment: depending on the scope here (number of wb's and sheets) you may be creating a ton of data frames, which is not a cheap/fast operation.  Consider one of the other packages that reads Excel.  Or consider transitioning your Excel files to .csv files and use `csv_reader` which would be really quick.

Comment: Is it possible to transition a workbook with multiple tabs into a csv? My understanding is that csv files only work with one excel tab, however I need to read multiple excel tabs.

Comment: well, it depends.  :).  Excel won't do it, but you could read the files with something like `openpyxl` and write them once and be done with it (one time conversion).  But if you are accessing/editing the Excel files or such, then that isn't a great plan.  You might try using just straight `openpyxl` to read the data in lieu of `pandas`.  I'm not sure which would be faster, but you could run an experiment(s).  If the data doesn't change, you could read it as you are doing now and then pickle it for next time, which would be insanely fast comparatively.  All depends on how you are using this!